# Troubleshooting VPN connection with Wireshark by decrypting IPSec packets

Tags: vpn, ssl, wireshark, ipsec

I'm having troubling establishing a VPN connection to a specific network and I'm not the only one having issues. As per their instructions, I'm using the standard VPN client built in windows with pre-shared key and username/password. After excluding all the usual stuff like checking for typos, rebooting related hardware, different firewalls, simple testing tools like nmap, etcetera I've turned to analyzing the packet traffic itself using wireshark. From the below screenshot, it would appear that a connection is successfully established including authentication, and VPN traffic ensues. However, within half a second, the connection is terminated again. The connection is based on IKEv1 and to get an understanding of what the different packets stand for this page here was very helpful here: [Understanding IPSec IKEv1 negotiation on Wireshark](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/understanding-ikev1-negotiation-on-wireshark-34187)

[image: VPN packages in Wireshark]

Now since the connection naturally is encrypted, I cannot directly read the packages as to get any idea of what goes wrong. Fortunately, it does appear that WireShark supports [ESP Payload Decryption](https://wiki.wireshark.org/ESP_Preferences) as long as one has access to all necessary information. So I went ahead and created an ESP SA entry by writing the following values:

- Protocol: IPv4
- Src IP: My local IP as indicated by Wireshark
- Dest IP: The VPN server IP as indicated by Wireshark
- SPI: *
- Encryption: AES-CBC
- Encryption Key: the encryption key
- Authentication: HMAC-SHA-384-192

However, I'm unsure what the authentication key could be, as to finalize the decryption setup. Also, I wouldn't I also need to add an entry to the ISAKMP's IKEv1 decryption table too? In that case, I'm not sure how to get a hold of the COOKIE and Encryption Key for that in my Windows environment, however.

This is not in my field of solid expertise, so I may have missed something, and if anyone could help me in the right direction, it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Decrypting ESP will most likely not help you debug why the SAs are deleted as that happens on the IKE/ISAKMP layer. And decrypting the latter will probably also not show you _why_ the termination happens, only that it does. So you better get your hands on the logs of the IKE daemons that are involved to see why the connection is terminated so soon.

Comment: Thanks! I will take this into consideration.

Comment: To add to this: The server people aren't very helpful, and use any excuse to blame the faulty connection to my computer or just typos. However, isn't it fair to deduce that the connection is authenticated and established without problems in the first place? So any connection problems (and I'm not the only one having issues) will not be because I did or have something wrong on my end???

Comment: I guess it depends on who initiated the termination. In the screenshot the IP addresses are masked, but their length is different. From that I'd guess the first Informational messages are sent by the client (shorter address). So try to see if there is something logged on the client in regards to terminating the SAs. The Informational messages could also contain something else (e.g. an `INITIAL_CONTACT` notify, or being used for DPD), so without a detailed log (or decrypting the messages) you can't be sure what exactly is going on.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful! So I located my local App logs (RasClient) and I got the following messages related to the termination of the connection: 
1. The user SYSTEM dialed a connection named [x] which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 720.
2. The user [y\z] dialed a connection named [x] which has terminated. The reason code returned on termination is 828.
I'm gonna try and look these up, but any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see some posts suggesting to uninstall all WAN miniports in Device Manager. I'll try that first!

Comment: OK, I fixed it thanks to your pointers! If you would you like to have credit added, please add an answer. Otherwise, I will eventually answer the question myself. Thanks for your help in any case!

Comment: Go ahead and describe how you fixed it, I didn't do much :)

Comment: @FedorAlexanderSteeman Would you mind posting how you resolved this? I'm facing the same issue, but am unable to find any solutions that work for me. My L2TP VPN connection just terminates immediately as well from my home network so I think it's a router issue, but not positive. I am able to connect through my phone hotspot.

Comment: @EdSweeney It's been a while, but I believed I fixed it by removing WAN Miniport under Device Manager, which were then automatically re-added again.